# About Half-Dragon mate and lifespan

Tags: dnd-3.5e, races

Is Half-Dragon able to mate with the parent race who is not Dragon?

If so, what kind of race will the child have?

What is the lifespan of Half-Dragon Human and Half-Dragon Kobold and so on?

Answer (score 2):

> Is Half-Dragon able to mate with the parent race who is not Dragon?
>
> If so, what kind of race will the child have?

Yes, this is possible:

> Half-dragons and draconic characters can make devoted couples, and most of their offspring are draconic.

<sup>(*Races of the Dragon* pg. 63)</sup>

It’s not abundantly clear whether this line is talking about a half-dragon–draconic creature couple, or talking about half-dragons and draconic creatures as being capable of being devoted as part of a couple (presumably including a non-draconic member), but in any event, the possibility of offspring is confirmed. The draconic creature template is indicated here, but note that this template is described as “descended from a dragon ancestor, though that ancestor could be many generations removed,” *Races of the Dragon* pg. 74. I believe there are instances in the books of “half-dragons” actually being only, say, a quarter dragon or even an eighth. I generally would be amenable to such a thing.

Of course, both the draconic and half-dragon template are very poor for player characters, particularly half-dragon. Level adjustment is just crippling, and it’s almost impossible to recover from an LA as high as +3.

> What is the lifespan of Half-Dragon Human and Half-Dragon Kobold and so on?

*Races of the Dragon* covers this, though not with as much detail as you might like:

> A dragon’s lifespan is truly remarkable—it can live millenium or longer, and even at the end of its life transform into a permanent part of the land or become ascendant and immortal. Half-dragons usually share the heritage of a less long-lived race and so might endure no more than a few centuries. Still, they are granted more time than most, and those born of a dragon–elf union can challenge ancient wyrms for longevity.

<sup>(*Races of the Dragon* pg. 61)</sup>